# ReOpen last active accordion after form submit

Tags: accordion, form-submit

I am submit a form which is present in 5th accordion and after submitting the form the page is getting reload and default first accordion is getting .active after reload.

I want the last active accordion to be active after page reload.

```
var query = $('#isOtherOptions').val();
        if(query=='true')
            {
               $(tabPanelNav).find('li').last().addClass('active');
               $('.configTab').addClass('active').show();

            }else{
                $(tabPanelNav).find('li').first().addClass('active');
                $(container).find('dd').first().addClass('active').show();

            $(tabPanelNav).addClass('full');

    });


    $('.panel-tab-list nav a').not('.active').on('click touchstart', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var contentContainer = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel'));
          $(this).closest('nav').find('.active').removeClass('active').end().end().closest('li').addClass('active').closest('.panel-tab-list').find('dd.active').hide();



        $(contentContainer).show().addClass('active');


    });
```

Comment: Anybody. please help!!!

Comment: $(tabPanelNav).find('li').first().addClass('active');
$(container).find('dd').first().addClass('active').show(); this is making it default to open after page refresh... how to make it last active tab to open again after page refresh